# Including two things it will check for in one if statement in python

Tags: python, variables, if-statement

lets say I have a program that runs like this in python

```
x=raw_input("Please enter name: ")
if x=="David" and "Jonathon"
   print "Whatever"
```

how do I get two things such as Jonathon and David so it excepts both of these scenarios and for both executes print "Whatever". I know that ["David" and "Jonathon"] isn't the proper syntax for this so I want to know what is. I also know how to do this be adding an elif statement but I want to know another way.

Comment: Maybe just `if x in ("David", "Jonathon"):`. Also don't you mean "David" or "Jonathon" ?

Comment: What tutorial are you using?  Have you looked at "conditional expressions" in a tutorial yet?

Answer (score 3):

You can do:

```
x=raw_input("Please enter name: ")

if x=="David" or x=="Jonathon":

    print "Whatever"
```

Or you can do:

```
names=["Bob","Joe"]
x=raw_input("What is your name?\n")
if x in names:
     print "Whatever"
```

If you are dealing with large data.

Comment: The second example should be `if x in names`.  (And if names is really large, you're better off making it a set than a list.)

Answer (score 2):

```
names = ["David", "Jonathon"]
x=raw_input("Please enter name: ")
if x in names:
    print "Whatever"
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for logical OR.  What you're trying to do here as far as I understand is say if x=="David" OR x=="Jonathon" then do something so you want the following.

Clearly x cannot have two values so AND will never evaluate to true.  This would be the correct code (or velociraptors version using an array)

```
x=raw_input("Please enter name: ")

if x=="David" or x=="Jonathon":

    print "Whatever"
```

Given the discussion, here's the whole hog using a simple config file (I've tested the conf.read().split() so please, no comments about it).  The config file would contain one name per line with no spaces (so no "firstname surname"):

```
conf = open('/path/to/config.txt','r')
names = conf.read().split()

x=raw_input("Please enter name: ")
if x in names:
    print "Whatever"
```

If your list of names had the potential to get very long, this would be the most maintainable solution.

Comment: A list is easier to modify if the requirements change.

Comment: @Velociraptors only mildly easier unless it's in a configuration file.  Otherwise you're still going into a core code file to update it.  I'm a big fan of config files when possible but I didn't think the original poster was quite ready to go into all that.

Comment: @Endophage I'm not sure I agree that it's only mildly easier. What if you need to check 10 names? That's a lot of `or x=="something"` vs items in a list.

Comment: @Velociraptors ...all of two characters if you don't put a space after the commas in your list.